# Using the Facebook login button: How can I let logged users to read restricted pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook, facebook-login

Using the Facebook login button:

1. How can I let logged users to read restricted pages?
2. How do I resctict a Web page?
3. Can I save basic user information into my data base?

I would appreciate exampes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each page you are hosting, you can set a permission or like you can mention to whom you want to share. Specify these to restrict some one to read your posts. Hope you expect this.

Comment: Thanks for answer me. How can I do it?

Comment: How can I set the permission. Could you give me an exaple? Thanks.